# How to make relative positioned html-video responsive

Tags: css, angular, html, typescript, html5-video

I am wondering if it is possible to make a **relative** positioned html5-video responsive. In other words, automatic resizing of the video with the correct aspect ratio.

Any ideas?

Comment: yes it's possible!, if you want more help and better answer please put some codes on your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Eg with CSS:

```
#video-id {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Or directly in the HTML:

```
<video width="100%" ...
```

As the video's width scales based on its parent width, the `auto` height will automatically scale with the correct aspect ratio. Vice versa to auto scale the width to height.

Note that with the HTML version leave the height blank (or width if you specify `height="100%"`) to maintain the `auto` status.

In CSS instead of setting `width` or `height` to `100%` you might want to set `max-width: 100%` etc., and on larger screens the video will not expand beyond its original resolution.

[Original source](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php) describing fluid width video.

Comment: but isn't your "Original Source" solving it with absolute positioning?

Comment: In that link when they discuss iframes and embedded content as alternatives to HTML5 video, their wrapper is `relative` and the content frame is `absolute` so that the embedded content fills the wrapper. As far as pure HTML videos go, the position attribute does not have a direct effect on aspect ratio so you can set it to whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

use this,

```
video {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

this will give width:100%, and height : auto as per aspect ratio...

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Just use % or vw, vh as units for width and height.

```
<video width="96%" height="54%" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```